# How to deselect the text of a combobox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox, krypton-toolkit

I have a krypton combo box which I data bind with a list of key-value pairs. What's happening is that when I set the selected item in code, it is highlighting the text. How can I prevent this or deselect the text?

I've tried the following:

```
// 1
combo.Select(0,0);
// 2
combo.Focus();
anotherControl.Focus();
// 3
combo.SelectionStart = 0;
combo.SelectionLength = combo.Text.Length;
// 4 
combo.SelectionStart = combo.Text.Length;
combo.SelectionLength = 0;
```

Nothing seems to work. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

I managed accomplishing this be overriding the OnPaint event of my control/window and doing

```
combobox1.SelectionLength = 0;
```

Comment: Doing this and I can't highlight the text later. Its getting deselected every time because the OnPaint method gets called often

Answer (score 4):

You simply have to place this code on generated event or button click where you want to deselect the text of a Combo Box

```
ComboBox1.SelectedItem = null;
```

Comment: The OP is not trying to change the selected item, he just wants to un-highlight the text.

Answer (score 3):

Try this out

```
combo.SelectedText = String.Empty;
```

Regarding your problem with focus: ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedtext.aspx))

> When the combo box loses focus, the selection point moves to the
>   beginning of the text and any selected text becomes unselected

So strange; why the following didn't work:

```
anotherControl.Focus();
```

Comment: it's weird when i click on it after its loaded and then click on something else then that focus thing works!??! it's driving me nuts

Comment: does your combobox is bound to some data source? If yes, try SelectedIndex = -1

Comment: it is bound, but i then choose an item from the list. It's basically a form that's being prepopulated from a db, so i need to select the correct item.

Answer (score 3):

I may have found a solution that works:

If you are using a form, subscribe to the form's Shown event.

**OR**

If you are using a UserControl (like I am), you can subscribe to the VisibleChanged event.

In the event, you can then do the following:

```
        foreach (ComboBox cbo in (this.Controls.Cast<Control>().Where(c => c is ComboBox).Select(c => (ComboBox) c)))
        {
            cbo.SelectionLength = 0;
        }
```

As an aside:

I ended up having to do this for a user control in which I added ComboBoxes to the control and then needed to later dynamically set their size. Setting the size caused the highlighting that the OP was encountering.

Answer (score 2):

I know its been a while since you asked this question. But here is what you can do

```
combo.selectedindex = -1;
```

Comment: Thanks, but i'm not trying to change the selected item, i just want to un-highlight the text.

Answer (score 2):

I know, ancient post, ancient technology, but this ugly oneliner worked for me:

```
cb.SelectedValueChanged += (s, e) => { cb.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { cb.SelectionStart = cb.Text.Length; }); };
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify whether the user is supposed to be able to edit the ComboBox values or not. If not, then `DropDownStyle` of the ComboBox should be set to `ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList`. This way the ComboBox will only allow  selecting existing values, users will not be able to type new values and the text will never be highlighted.

Answer (score 1):

On event SelectedIndexChanged add the timer which will be executed only once after 10 milliseconds.

```
new System.Threading.Timer((s) =>
            {
                comboBox1.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    comboBox1.Select(0, 0);
                }));
            }, null, 10, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
```

Answer (score 1):

'Select' doesn't work for me. But I found a very simple trick. 
Add this right into the SelectedIndexChanged-Event:

```cs
comboBox1.Hide();
comboBox1.Show();
```

Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you might be doing in the background ie fired events etc. However in the combox selectedindexchanged event you can add anotherControl.Select().

That should:)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I do:

```
private void faceComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     this.ActiveControl = cancelButton;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

these 3 lines helped me:

```
cbInstallationType.SelectionStart = 0;
cbInstallationType.SelectionLength = 0;
cbInstallationType.TabIndex = 99;
```

TabIndex has to be not the first one, so that it is not the first item in the form

Comment: I've the same problem as the OP and this didn't helped

Answer (score 0):

In my case selecting appeared after resize. This solved it:

```
textBox.Resize += (sender, args) =>
{
    Control c = sender as Control;
    if (c == null || c.Parent == null)
        return;

    c.Focus();
    c.Parent.Focus();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to the "SelectedIndexChanged" event, which has the task to set the focus of the ComboBox.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.Focus();
}
```

Subscribe to the "Paint" event from the main form. The deselection takes place in this event handler:

```
private void MainForm_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.SelectionLength = 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't care how old this is. We're building a knowledge base.

I use D5 (and probably prior versions are the same). You need to use:

```
Combobox.SelLength :=  0;
```

Also, if that doesn't work, this one does: Avoid the default Style (csDropDown).
  And set it to:

```
Combobox.Style := csDropDownList;
```

as Alex suggested.

Thank you. Works great!

Comment: Pardon me but the syntax you have shown here doesn't look like C# at all.

Comment: D5? Do you mean Delphi? In a [C#] tagged question?

Answer (score -1):

Use Style --> csOwnerDrawFixed.

Comment: Can you elaborate further on how exactly this answers the question?